How does react process redirects?
I'm new to working with react and I think i have spent considerable time in researching about my issue/problem but no luck. I have a react FE and a rails BE. The FE is just a login page with a couple of auth buttons and a form that has login and password. For the form, I am sending an axios post call from the react LoginPage component (login page) and this triggers 2 redirects on the rails BE, authenticates the user and logs them in. The flow goes like this-> post call triggering redirect to auth controller endpoint which redirects to token controller. When it reaches the token controller is i expect the user to login, but it ends up rendering the same login page. When i copy paste the token URL, and paste it on another tab, it logs me in. I am not using React Router. This is the axios post call from react LoginPage component-
this.submit = (event) => {
      //event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({ inlineNotificationError: null });
      const formData = {
        login: this.model.login,
        password: this.model.password
      };

      const params = this.props.loginData.loginPathRequestParams
      const combinedParams = { ...formData, ...params };
  
      axios.post(this.props.loginData.loginPathUrl, combinedParams, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ inlineNotificationError: null});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ inlineNotificationError: { title: error.response.data.error }});
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.model.login = '';
        this.model.password = '';
      });  
    };

I am expecting the page to log the user in after getting redirected to token endpoint in the rails backend.

If i understood you correctly you can try this:
// in your App.jsx

useEffect(() => {
  const sessionId = Cookies.get('sessionId'); // you might need a cookie library like js-cookie 
  // or look for a param in your URL
  // const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  // const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');

  if (sessionId) {
    redirect('/home'); // or whatever route you need to
    // or something like setState({ isAuthorized: true })
  }
}, [])

The general idea is that you need to send some indicator to your frontend that the user is logged in. Then in your App.jsx component, or wherever you like, you need to handle the routing logic based on that indicator.
TLDR:

Send request from FE
Process the request
Redirect from BE with some indication whether the user is logged in or not (cookie, url param)
In FE/React handle the logic at top level to redirect from the login form (or not)

Hope i could help
PS: Why not use ReactRouter? It would be very convenient to handle that kind of logic
